# iconPacks with MouseLeftButtonDown throws an exception

Tags: mahapps.metro

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXX.Apps.UI.Wpf.UserControls.AccountTile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXX.Apps.UI.Wpf.UserControls"
             xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
```

...

```
<iconPacks:PackIconModern Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="12" Kind="Delete" MouseLeftButtonDown="deleteIcon_Click" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

gives me

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line
>   number '8' and line position '14'.

Inner:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MahApps.Metro.IconPacks,
>   Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131044)

... only when I have the `MouseLeftButtonDown` attribute on the icon.

Obviously my own assembly is signed. I have added the 'MahApps.Metro.IconPacks' as NuGet package. Don't tell me you didn't sign your assembly?

How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks#strong-naming Apparently someone thought it would be a great idea if they don't sign the assembly they are distributing!!!

Comment: Yes, cause why should this be the default? There are only some special situations where you need strong named/signed dlls, so I decided that I don't need that.

Comment: Please review my code above. Is there anything I can do to bind an event to the icon without the icon pack being signed? What is the work-around, place a transparent rectangle on top of the icon and bind the event to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the icon pack is not strong signed, you could try using it like this:

```
<Button Content="{iconPacks:PackIconModern Delete, Width=12, Height=12}" Width="12" Height="12" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" Click="deleteIcon_Click" />
```

And here's the style:

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## Output

[image: Output]

Please note that if you set width and height, clicking outside the icon will not fire the event